# Does anybody know what this IC is?

Tags: identification

I tried different search keywords combinations, but I couldn’t find a datasheet, nor a hint of what this IC could be. Maybe someone who’s familiar with it could give me a clue. [image: APT619AP 0609A BJC6124]
The IC is on a board that was part of the control panel of a home theater. The options were volume up and down, surround 2.1 or 5.1 and mute. The brand was National Star, as far as I can recall. Thanks in advance.

[image: Logic board]
[image: Logic board]

Comment: @Damián - Hi, From the photos, I'll just make two short comments. You haven't asked this as a repair question (it's difficult to make them on-topic here, so that's good!) but assuming you believe there's a fault on that board: (a) There's very questionable soldering in several places including, but not only, where `C1` and `IR1` used to be (and possible solder bridges in both of those places). (b) The fault on the board might be elsewhere e.g. power problems, which could cause the (suspected MCU, per *Spehro's* answer) IC to misbehave. I would not start by trying to replace the IC. Good luck!

Comment: The pin mapping of the ceramic resonator, power supplies, and even reset pin, seem to match PIC16x84 and PIC16x54 microcontrollers for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the ceramic resonator and load capacitors connected to pins 15 and 16, it's almost surely a microcontroller with a custom program in OTP or flash memory. And typically the program memory is read-protected for the security of the manufacturer's firmware.

So more than likely it's not the sort of thing you'll be able to buy from other sources than the original, such as a used board or repair part.

Comment: Please note SamGibson's comment- the chip is not the most likely failure point. The other parts are all easily inspected and are very common parts most likely.

Comment: Certain Microchip PICs, e.g. PIC16C5x, come in DIP-18 and have Osc pins at 15 &16.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a remote control decoder. LED1 though LED4 have drive transistors and LED5 doesn't - I'd theorise it's an IR LED to receive remote codes.

Comment: I can recall a remote control being part of the original package.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a led decoder for each switch on the board. Every time you push each of the switch the led indicator will glow that indicate which program was used. It's a signal decoder ic and not commonly failed in a circuits. My advice is to resolder each components. Nevertheless, check the vdc supply and test each transistor on the pcb for failure. Good luck!.